# Problem with updating timer in an animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to make a countdown timer using flutter, but the problem is, my timer seemingly does not update, I am unable to understand what could be the issue.
[dartPad link to run the code.](https://dartpad.dev/90bf084d626c2d78f683f2f235155ec7)

Also I would like to know how to run the timer in reverse, that is starting from 0 seconds.

Comment: Are you sure you shared the correct code? I didn't see any timer.

Comment: Corrected the code link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error here

```
Duration duration = controller.duration;
```

Duration is always 1 minute, it's not related to the progress. Use this instead to show an increasing timer (starting in 0)

```
Duration duration = controller.lastElapsedDuration;
```

And use this to implement the same but in a countdown manner (starting in 1 minute)

```
Duration duration = controller.duration - controller.lastElapsedDuration;
```